# Create an EFI partition while installing Ubuntu 21.04 in another disk partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, windows-10, 21.04

How can I create an EFI partition while installing Ubuntu 21.04 in another disk partition where I also have Windows 10 installed?

Comment: Either disconnect the existing disk with ESP or remove boot flag of the same both temporarily while installing to other disk.

Comment: you need to expand your question with details about what specifically you have tried to avoid proposed solutions which you have already tried unsuccessfully. Please read askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  and then [edit] accordingly

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to a screenshot of Windows Disk Management in Windows 10 that shows the existing partitions on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Ubuntu can utilize your existing EFI partition. You also need to make sure that your new Ubuntu partition is formatted with a GPT partition table. The installer handles the rest automatically.

1. Use an Ubuntu live USB to boot your computer.
2. Connect to the internet
3. Use the `apt` package manager to install `gparted`. You may need to `update` & `upgrade` first`.
4. When you open `gparted`, see if a there is a small EFI partition beside your Windows partition. If there is not, your hardware probably doesn't support BIOS. If an EFI partition is there, your Ubuntu installer will automatically use that one.
5. Resize your Windows partition with `gparted`. Leave at least a bit of extra space in the Windows partition.
6. Use the `fdisk` utility to format the remaining partition to a type of `linux filesystem` and to a `GPT` partition table - NOT `DOS/MBR`. Make sure to write your changes to disk. (Lots of great `fdisk` tutorials on YouTube if this part sounds like Greek).
   7.Run the installer on your new formatted partition. Since you have a `GPT` partition table and and existing EFI partition you'll be set.